# best ui framework for mobile website

Tags: jquery, mobile, web, mobile-website

I am looking for a fast and lightweight ui framework to build a simple mobile website. I have already tried jquery mobile ,but it is slow and its too heavy for the kind of website I wish to build. The average load time using jquery mobile for my site is around 3s which is even higher on slower networks that uses a gprs connection.

I used this website to run a load time test http://mobitest.akamai.com/m/index.cgi

Comment: 3ms to load a page is slow? I hope you are talking about seconds :)

Comment: yup sorry...typo there..will correct it..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think 3ms isn't slow at all!

But try **Kendo UI** from **Telerik**. It is really fast and you have huge possibilities, although it costs "a bit". If you use it professional it is great ;)

Comment: is there any alternative to kendou which is free to use

Comment: I think there is a trial, and a free version but it contains only a few featuers

Look at it here: http://www.kendoui.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try [**HTML5 boilerplate mobile**](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile)

I prefer this as default to start a project

Comment: do u have any tutorial links for this

Comment: same http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile click on 'I'm new here: plz explain why it's so awesome, first.'

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is the best mobile ui framework that is build with top of angular.js and now angular team rebuild their framework from group up and created angular 2 with lot of changes, like that ionic team rebuild their own and came up with ionic 2 with amazing features.

For more details please check the below link.

[https://sourcefreeze.com/best-mobile-ui-frameworks-using-html5-css-and-js/](http://sourcefreeze.com/best-mobile-ui-frameworks-using-html5-css-and-js/)